# mysql get previous field

Tags: mysql, get

I have data in mysql table like this

---

**no**    **code**

---

1      03
2      (null)
3      (null)
4      02
5      (null)
6      (null)
7      05
8      (null)
9      (null)

---

what's query i must type that the data like this

---

**no**    **code**

---

1      03
2      03
3      03
4      02
5      02
6      02
7      05
8      05
9      05

---

Comment: What have you tried? Care to provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT no, code = (@n := COALESCE(code, @n))
FROM MY_TABLE
ORDER BY no;
```